# How to create a multi module project(subproject) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, maven, project, multi-module

In java, there are various ways to create multiple module project. Maven provides extensive support for it.

I am wondering if such a feature is available in ruby.

Why we need it:
A full-stack project has middle tier, front end html and js controller code. This will help in categorize each of them.

Comment: [Rake](https://github.com/ruby/rake) (Ruby make) is a thing, but Ruby doesn't need a build system; it's not a statically-compiled language. The terms you're most likely looking for are "mixins" and "dependency management," but it's hard to search for those things unless you're already familiar with Ruby's ecosystem.

Comment: Do you mean like creating a gem that depends on another gem?

Answer (score 0):

### Modules and Gems

In Ruby, a [Module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Module.html) is a class-like object that collects methods and constants, and can be mixed into other classes. That's probably not what you're really asking about, but other solutions generally build on top of Ruby's Module and [Class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Class.html) semantics.

You're more likely to be looking for something like [RubyGems](https://guides.rubygems.org/) and [Bundler](https://bundler.io/) to manage libraries and dependencies. The documentation for each is fairly extensive.

Frameworks like Ruby on Rails also offer additional capabilities to inject gems and modules directly into the codebase, but it's arguably more common in Rails to build out these capabilities with gems and bundles. An exhaustive treatment of all the various ways to extend Rails (e.g. vendored gems, plugins, engines, etc.) is beyond the scope of a reasonable Stack Overflow answer, though. I mention some of them here in passing to help you search for the right documentation for your specific use cases.